# Handling Null in MVC Model

Tags: model-view-controller, model, null

I am facing DateTime null Error. My data comes from SQL server through stored procedures in MVC project. In MVC, Employee model receive the data in List and pass it to the View through the Employee Controller. Following is the code:

```
  public List<Employee> GetEmployeesByUserName(string username)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Startup.MTSConn);

        List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();

        using (conn)
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spRetrievEmployeesByUserName", conn))
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                conn.Open();
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                //Convert Data to List

                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {

                    employeesList.Add(new Employee
                    {
                        UserName = row["UserName"].ToString(),
                        KOCNo = row["KOCNo"].ToString(),
                        Name = row["Name"].ToString(),
                        Designation = row["Designation"].ToString(),
                        
                        **DOB = row["DOB"]==DBNull ? DBNull :  Convert.ToDateTime(row["DOB"])**
```

> Here I want to check if the field is null then return null otherwise convert it to DateTime. In employee model it is already set to null 'public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }'
> });

```
                }
            }
            return empList;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use entity to get the data from the database. However, to tackle this issue try do something like this

```
                  foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                       if (row["DOB"] != null) 
    
    
                        employeesList.Add(new Employee
                        {
                            UserName = row["UserName"].ToString(),
                            KOCNo = row["KOCNo"].ToString(),
                            Name = row["Name"].ToString(),
                            Designation = row["Designation"].ToString(),
                            
                            **DOB = row["DOB"].Convert.ToDateTime()**
                            }
                           else 
                         {                   
                              employeesList.Add(new Employee
                        {
                            UserName = row["UserName"].ToString(),
                            KOCNo = row["KOCNo"].ToString(),
                            Name = row["Name"].ToString(),
                            Designation = row["Designation"].ToString(),
                            DOB = null
                            
                           
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Fadi, I will give it try, I was thinking if I can use the ternary oprator in model while collecting data.